# How do I only retrieve numbers in an EditText instead of the whole String?

Tags: android-edittext, double, tostring, gettext, value-of

```
Double value = Double.valueOf(temp.getText().toString());
```

Let's say editText temp is 32 Celsius.
I only want to get 32 instead of "32 Celsius" so how would I be able to do this? Is this possible?

I'm a newbie with Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way that comes into my mind is

```
Double value = Double.valueOf(temp.getText().toString().split(" ")[0]);
```

which splits the string using the space and only takes the first value in the generated array.

This works if the user enters something like "[any_number] [any other string, even more words]".
i.e.: "32 Celsius", "952 years ago", "4 pieces of cake", ...

Comment: What if 32 Fahrenheit was an input a user gave. How would I do that then? I always just want the numbers, whatever String they enter afterwards doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: I mean I don't always know what exact what word the user is going to enter. Do I have to know the exact word in order for it to be excluded from retrieving the text?

Answer (score 1):

use *android:inputType="number"* in your EditText layout